# Social.ReportProgress method with Google Play Games Plugin always returns false

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I ran into an issue with the Google Play Games Plugin provided by Google for the Unity3D editor. I've just included the plugin in my unity project and when I put the app build on my android device, I can sign in the Google Play Games with my Google account. However, my achievements are never modified on line because the callback of the method Social.ReportProgress returns always "false". (the bool success)

```
// unlock achievement (achievement ID "Cfjewijawiu_QA")
Social.ReportProgress("Cfjewijawiu_QA", 100.0f, (bool success) => {
  // handle success or failure
});
```

I've checked that I use the correct ID for my achivements. The difference between my code and this official piece of code provided by Google on github is the percentage. For instance, my app can put "33.3333" for the percentage. When I tried to put the same percentage on the method (100.0f), the bool success was also false. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem.

On the github repository of the plugin, I took this piece of code for the GPG initialization :

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
    // enables saving game progress.
    .EnableSavedGames()
    // registers a callback to handle game invitations received while the game is not running.
    .WithInvitationDelegate(this.Debug)
    // registers a callback for turn based match notifications received while the
    // game is not running.
    .WithMatchDelegate(this.Debug)
    .Build();

PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
```

The achievement report works very well when I removed this section in my init class on Unity. I think there is some issue in these lines but I don't know where.

Moreover, I learned that I cannot set a custom percent value like 33.333. The value must be 0.0f for lock achievement and 100.0f for unlocking achievement. If you put a value greater than 0.0f, this value will be automatically considered to 100.0f. If you want to put custom steps on the achievement, you must use the increment achievement on the Google Play Console.